# remove duplicate string and empty string

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let undefined = ["string"; ""; "string"; "boolean";"";"innermost"]
```

I have a list and I want to write a function that return a list without duplicate and empty string list. For example the `undefined` list above will return :

```
["string"; "boolean"; "innermost"]
```

I write this function it return for me without duplicate but how can I add the condition with testing an empty string.

```
let rec uniquify = function
| [] -> []
| x::xs -> x :: uniquify (List.filter ((<>) x) xs)
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pipe the result to `List.filter (fun s -> s <> "")` to remove the empty string afterwards. That's the simple, compositional way, yo u could also hack your function to drop it silently

```
let rec uniquify = function
| [] -> []
| x::xs ->
  (if x = "" then [] else [x]) @ uniquify (List.filter ((<>) x) xs)
```

Note that your function is quadratic, you can have better complexity by sorting the list first, or by converting to a set and back. [Batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) has functions to do that for you.

```
let do_stuff list =
  let open Batteries in
  List.remove (List.sort_unique String.compare list) ""
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a set of already seen strings:

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String)
let uniquify list =
  let rec iter acc set list =
    match list with
     | [] -> List.rev acc
     | s :: tail ->
       if StringSet.mem s set then
          iter acc set tail
       else
          iter (s :: acc) (StringSet.add s set) tail
  in
  iter [] StringSet.empty list
```

The first line define the type of set of strings.

Then, uniquify calls an auxiliary function to either add a never seen string to both the list and the set, or just discard the string. The `acc` is used to make the iteration tail recursive (and thus, avoid stack overflows on long lists).

Using this scheme is better since the complexity is in O(N.log N) instead of N².

Comment: @Febrice Le Fessant I tried your code and at line 8 (iter s set tail) the compiler give me this error: Error: "This expression has type StringSet.elt = string but an expression was expected of type 'a list."

Comment: There were a little mistake at line 8, iter's first argument is a string list and not just a string.
I just tried it on [TryOCaml](http://try.ocamlpro.com/) and it works fine now.